# Split String into smaller words by length variable in c#

Tags: c#, string

Hi I have a string paragraph containing 25 words and 300 characters, I want to set it in set of labels which can be contain 40 characters. I am trying it as below code with character lengths.

```
public static List<string> _mSplitByLength(this string str, int maxLength)
{
    List<string> _a = new List<string>();
    for (int index = 0; index < str.Length; index += maxLength)
    {
        _a.Add(str.Substring(index, Math.Min(maxLength, str.Length - index)));
    }
    return _a;
}
```

with above code i can split string into 40 character but problem is that it split words also.

suppose my string is `"My school Name is stack over flow High school."` which is 46 characters so with my code its getting like this

```
list 1 = "My school Name is stack over flow High s"
list 2 = "chool."
```

My question is how to split string on basis of words. if last word not comming so it should be transfer to next list.

my Aim is

```
list 1 = "My school Name is stack over flow High "
list 2 = "school."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string text = "My school Name is stack over flow High school.";
List<string> lines =
    text
        .Split(' ')
        .Aggregate(new [] { "" }.ToList(), (a, x) =>
        {
            var last = a[a.Count - 1];
            if ((last + " " + x).Length > 40)
            {
                a.Add(x);
            }
            else
            {
                a[a.Count - 1] = (last + " " + x).Trim();
            }
            return a;
        });
```

I get this out:

```
My school Name is stack over flow High 
school.
```